# RPLY parser returns ValueError

Tags: python, parsing, lexer

I am trying to write a basic programming language. I am using RPLY for lexing and parsing. I have written 4 tokens required in assigning a value to a variable:

```
    self.lexer.add('INT', r'd+')
    self.lexer.add('STRING', r'"[^"]*"')
    self.lexer.add('ASSIGN', r'\=')
    self.lexer.add('IDENT', r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*')
```

My parser generator accepts these tokens

```
        self.pg = ParserGenerator(
        # A list of all token names accepted by the parser.
        ['NUMBER', 'PRINT', 'OPEN_PAREN', 'CLOSE_PAREN',
         'SEMI_COLON', 'SUM', 'SUB', 'MUL', 'INT', 'STRING', 'IDENT', 'ASSIGN'],
        precedence=[
            ('left', ['SUM','SUB']),
            ('left', ['STRING', 'IDENT', 'ASSIGN'])
        ]
    )
```

Here's the production for creating a variable

```
    @self.pg.production('identifier : STRING IDENT ASSIGN expression')
    @self.pg.production('identifier : INT IDENT ASSIGN expression')
    def identifier(p):
        return p
```

And when I try to run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    parser.parse(tokens).eval()
  File "/xxx/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rply/parser.py", line 60, in parse
    self.error_handler(lookahead)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/Project/parser.py", line 53, in error_handle
    raise ValueError(token)
ValueError: Token('IDENT', 'string')
```

Input file:

```
    string oki = "ssds"
    print(oki);
```

It parses string into IDENT where string should be parsed into STRING token instead. Precedence is set, but maybe it doesn't recognize it?

Comment: The file `parser.py` in your project directory should be renamed to something else, like `parser_gen.py`. This is because a file with the name `parser.py` already exists in the `site-packages` for `rply`. Read: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap

Comment: Renamed, still get the same error. File "/home/xxx/xxx/Project/generatePars.py", line 53, in error_handle